# Linux Web Server Permissions - Write But Not View/Modify/Delete

Tags: linux, permissions, ftp

I have a Joomla website with Chronoforms installed.
I have created a contact form with it which includes a File Upload.

For security reasons i cant have anyone viewing the files/folder. But obviously the folder needs to be able to be written too.

The file is emailed upon upload so there is no reason for anyone apart from the Admin VIA FTP to view the folder. It is purely there for records sake and as a backup to the email.

What permissions do i need to set to achieve this?

I have had a look around StackExchange but not found anything that would fit my issue.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Options include:

- A .htaccess file in the upload folder containing the line:

> deny from all

will prevent access to files in the folder when directly accessed. If the file is sent from Chronoforms as an attachment, then this may be suitable.

This method is used by DocMAN, where the files are all accessed by PHP calls rather than direct URLS, which is not how the file downloads in Chronoforms work by default, so you may need to take that into consideration.

- Create the Upload folder below the public_html folder, which is then inaccessible via the web.